# Convert SQL query to MySQL. Categories Nest level

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table in phpmyadmin called categories, with columns ID, ParentID, Name, NestLevel.

At the moment I have all but Nest level populated. And I want to find out which Level each category is in the tree.

So after a bit of googling, I found the following [article](http://www.sql-server-helper.com/functions/get-tree-node-level.aspx):

However, this is for sql server, not mysql. The snippet in question is as follows:

```
-- Step #1: Add [Level] Column to the Table
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Hierarchy] ADD [Level] INT NULL
GO

-- Step #2: Set Level = 1 For Rows With No Parents
UPDATE [dbo].[Hierarchy]
SET [Level] = 1
WHERE [ParentID] IS NULL
GO

-- Step #3: Set the Level of all Remaining Rows
WHILE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [dbo].[Hierarchy] WHERE [Level] IS NULL) > 0
BEGIN
    UPDATE A
    SET [Level] = B.[Level] + 1
    FROM [dbo].[Hierarchy] A INNER JOIN [dbo].[Hierarchy] B
                                     ON A.[ParentID] = B.[ID]
    WHERE A.[Level] IS NULL AND
          B.[Level] IS NOT NULL
END
GO
```

So, first i deleted all [] and all instances of GO, END, BEGIN and replaced all instances of [dbo].[hierarchy] with `categories`.

So now, steps 1 and 2 work perfectly. However, step 3 is the one that is giving me errors and have no clue why.

I will also be eventually be calling this all via a php script with (if this makes any difference to the answer):

```
$sql = "query";
database_queryModify($sql,$result);
```

Anyone knows the issue?

Thanks
John

EDIT: The error I get is:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your 
MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 
'WHILE SELECT COUNT(*) FROM categories WHERE Level IS NULL > 0 UPDATE A ' 
at line 1
```

Comment: Be specific about the errors you get.

Comment: Have a look at this                                          http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/ It uses MySQL

Comment: @AndriusNaruševičius question edited with the error i am getting